# How to ignore field from Spring Data JPA projection mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm building a REST API for a Q&A web application. It has communities where each community is defined by an id, name, description, members, and others. Right now, I have an endpoint for fetching the given community data `/api/v1/communities/{id}`.

The response looks like this

```
 {
    "name": "VIP",
    "id": 5,
    "displayName": "VIP",
    "subtopics": [
        "Sports"
    ],
    "primaryTopic": "Gaming",
    "about": "",
    "isPublic": false,
    "isPrivate": true,
    "isRestricted": false
}
```

The response is a DTO that's mapped automatically using Spring Data Projection. Now, I want to add a new field to the DTO. The field called `isMember` and it should store whether the currently authenticated user is a member of the given community.

```java
public interface CommunityResponse {
    Long getId();

    String getName();

    String getDisplayName();

    String getAbout();

    @Value("#{target.primaryTopic.getDisplayName()}")
    String getPrimaryTopic();

    @Value("#{target.getSubtopicsDisplayNames()}")
    Set<String> getSubtopics();

    @Value("#{target.isPublic()}")
    @JsonProperty("isPublic")
    boolean isPublic();

    @Value("#{target.isPrivate()}")
    @JsonProperty("isPrivate")
    boolean isPrivate();

    @Value("#{target.isRestricted()}")
    @JsonProperty("isRestricted")
    boolean isRestricted();
   
    // boolean isMember();

}
```

I thought about using Class-based projection. I converted the interface into a class and added the `isMember` field to the DTO and called `setIsMember()` inside the service class, but I got an error that says `no property 'isMember' found for type 'CommunityResponse'`

As far as I understand, each field in a projection class or interface must either share the same name as a field in the entity or it should be derived from other fields using Spring’s expression language.

The problem is that `isMember` is not a field from the entity and I don't know how to derive it using Spring’s expression language. The logic for initializing `isMember` looks like this:

```java
       public boolean isMember(Long communityId, Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return userAccountRepository.findByEmail(userDetails.getUsername()).map(user -> {
            return user.getJoinedCommunities().stream().anyMatch(community -> community.getId() == communityId);
        }).orElse(false);
    }
```

Other classes

`UserAccount.java`

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Firstname is required")
    private String firstname;
    @NotBlank(message = "Lastname is required")
    private String lastname;
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
    private String username;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String hashedPassword;
    private Instant creationDate;
    private Boolean activated;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "members")
    private Set<Community> joinedCommunities;
}
```

`Community.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "community")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Community {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CommunityType type;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private String displayName;

    private String about;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Topic primaryTopic;

    @CollectionTable(name = "subtopic")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Topic.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "topic")
    private Set<Topic> subtopicSet;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "community_members",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "community_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "member_id") })
    private Set<UserAccount> members;


    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public boolean isPublic() {
        return type == CommunityType.PUBLIC;
    }

    public boolean isPrivate() {
        return type == CommunityType.PRIVATE;
    }

    public boolean isRestricted() {
        return type == CommunityType.RESTRICTED;
    }

    public Set<String> getSubtopicsDisplayNames() {
        return getSubtopicSet().stream().map(Topic::getDisplayName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

}
```

`CommunityRepository.java`

```java
public interface CommunityRepository extends JpaRepository<Community, Long> {
    Optional<CommunityResponse> findCommunityById(Long id);

    List<CommunityResponse> findCommunityResponseBy();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about using Class-based projection. I converted the interface into a class and added the isMember field to the DTO

You could try to derive `isMember` within JPQL query constructing class-based projection:

```java
@Query("select new com.my.project.DTO(c.id, c.name, (:user member of c.members)) from Community c ...")
List<CommunityResponse> findCommunityResponseBy(UserAccount user);
```

Alternatively, in interface-based projection you could try

```java
@Value("#{target.members.contains(#user)}")
boolean isMember;
```

where `#user` is the argument of `findBy` method.

Comment: I tried interface-based projection but I got this error: `At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.`


This is the repository method

`List<CommunityResponse> findCommunityResponseBy(UserAccount user);`


I also tried with the @param annotation but the same error occurs

`List<CommunityResponse> findCommunityResponseBy(@Param("user") UserAccount user);`

Comment: If you add a parameter then you need to change method's name to `List<CommunityResponse> findCommunityResponseByUser(UserAccount user)`

Comment: That would fetch only the communities that the user belongs to, right? But I want to fetch all communities. The user is needed as a helper to compute the `isMember` property, not to filter out entries. The `isMember` field should be true if the authenticated user is a member of that community and false otherwise. In the frontend I want to list all communities and on each line add a join button. The join button will be disabled if the authenticated user is already a member of that community.  So it's kind of an optimization to avoid sending multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: You still can use interface-based projection in this case, just add `@Query` over the method and override the logic with JPQL

Comment: With JPQL, hibernate keeps adding the WHERE clause for filtering out entries. This is the query it generated: `select community0_.display_name as col_0_0_, ? in (members1_.member_id) as col_1_0_ from community community0_ cross join community_members members1_ where community0_.id=members1_.community_id`. And this is the repository method declaration: 
`@Query("SELECT new net.askvio.controllers.communities.CommunityInfo(c.displayName, :user member of c.members) FROM Community c")
    List<CommunityInfo> findCommunityInfoBy(UserAccount user);`

Comment: It's not filtering, it's actually cross joining of two tables, so all items will be present in result set

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Projections is very limited and might run into N + 1 issues when doing stuff like this. So using a dedicated DTO query would be advisable. I think though that this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Community.class)
public interface CommunityResponse {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();

    String getDisplayName();

    String getAbout();

    @JsonIgnore
    @Mapping("primaryTopic")
    Topic getPrimaryTopicEnum();

    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Topic> getSubtopicSet();

    default String getPrimaryTopic() {
        return getPrimaryTopicEnum().getDisplayName();
    }

    default Set<String> getSubtopics() {
        return getSubtopicSet().stream().map(Topic::getDisplayName).collect(toSet());
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    CommunityType getType();

    @JsonProperty("isPublic")
    default boolean isPublic() {
        return getType() == CommunityType.PUBLIC;
    }

    @JsonProperty("isPrivate")
    default boolean isPrivate() {
        return getType()== CommunityType.PRIVATE;
    }

    @JsonProperty("isRestricted")
    default boolean isRestricted() {
        return getType()== CommunityType.RESTRICTED;
    }

    @Mapping("case when this member of User[id = :currentUserId].joinedCommunities then true else false end")
    boolean isMember();

}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`CommunityResponse a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, CommunityResponse.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<CommunityResponse> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!